# How to find the largest number in an object using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, return

Here is my dataset:

```
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]
```

I'm trying to find and return the largest number in this object using a for loop. I know there are probably easier, more efficient routes but I'm specifically working on for loops.

Instead of simply returning the largest price, I however want to return the itemName of the largest price item. My code currently is only returning the largest price: 299.99 and not the itemName "Creation 3005". How would I return this information using for loops? This is what I have so far.

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
  let expensive = items[0].price || null; 
  let number = null;
  let name = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    number = items[i].price;
    expensive = Math.max(expensive, number); 
    }
   return expensive;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reassign the outer variable only if the item you're iterating over has a higher price:

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
];
function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
  let highestPriceSoFar = 0;
  let nameOfHighestPriceSoFar;
  for (const { itemName, price } of items) {
    if (price > highestPriceSoFar) {
      highestPriceSoFar = price;
      nameOfHighestPriceSoFar = itemName;
    }
  }
  console.log(nameOfHighestPriceSoFar);
}
mostExpensiveItemName(items);
```

Comment: Wow. This was my first ever question posted here and if I would have known I could have gotten such a comprehensive answer in such a short time, I would have asked a question a long time ago. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Quick question: the line that reads

```for (const { itemName, price } of items) {
```

does that replace ```for(let i = 0; i < items.length, i++)``? I would assume that is the line that is actually looping through the dataset?

Comment: I also like this answer because say for instance the dataset was a shopping cart. The way the variables are defined as empty shopping cart or empty array would return undefined instead of null. An undefined result would immediately raise a flag and cause one to check their variables like a built in safety clause.

Comment: *I would assume that is the line that is actually looping through the dataset?* Yes, it loops through the array, but is more concise and abstract (which is good!) than messing with indicies.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

you could use `forEach` like this

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]

let maxPrice = 0, product;
items.forEach(el => {
  if(el.price > maxPrice){ 
     maxPrice = el.price;
     product = Object.assign({}, el); // for make sure you made a new copy not a reference 
  }
});

console.log(product, maxPrice)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you decide to look at alternatives to `for` loops, these sort of questions are incredibly easy using `reduce`.

```js
const selectHigherPrice = (state, item) => state.price > item.price ? state : item

const initialState = items[0]

items.reduce(selectHigherPrice, initialState)

// One line
items.reduce((state, item) => state.price > item.price ? state : item)
```

- `state` is initialised as the first item in the `items` list
- The `selectHigherPrice` function is called for each item in the array
- If the current `state.price` property is greater than the `item.price` property:

  - `state` is returned
  - otherwise `item` is returned and becomes the `state` variable when `selectHigherPrice` is called for the next item in the list.

If you are sure your list will have items you can omit the second argument

Comment: I appreciate you giving an alternative method and also explaining what was going on. This would be a much easier way of solving this. After looking up some info on the reduce array method and following your answer, this is a perfect example of the easier method that I knew had to exist. I’m sure I’ll get to using reduce in even more complicated ways. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, welcome to Stackoverflow. Don't forget to make someones answer as accepted once you are satisfied. If you are interested in this style of programming I cannot recommend [this series](https://randycoulman.com/blog/2016/05/24/thinking-in-ramda-getting-started/) more.

Comment: I skimmed the site and bookmarked it for future reference. I'm still at the beginning of my programming journey but I'm sure as I get more advanced that Ramda will pop back up and I'll more under my belt to understand it. Thanks for the resource.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
   let expensive = items[0]; 
   let number = null;
   let name = null;
   for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      number = items[i];
      expensive = expensive.price < number.price ? number:;
   }
   return expensive;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do:

```js
function mostExpensive(objArray){
  const m = objArray.map(o=>o.price);
  return objArray[m.indexOf(Math.max(...m))];
}
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
];
const me = mostExpensive(items);
console.log(me); console.log(me.price);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. It's cleaner, more expressive and you're not conflating two different concerns:

- finding the most expensive item, and
- determining its name

```
function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
  let item = mostExpensiveItem(items);
    return item ? item.Name : undefined;
}

function mostExpensiveItem(items) {
  let max;

  for ( const item of items ) {
     max = !item                  ? item   // 1st item in list
         : item.price > max.price ? item   // replace existing w/new most-expensive item
         :                          max  ; // keep existing
  }

  return max ;
}
```

Comment: This does make sense if you’re trying to keep the concerns separate. I’ll keep this in mind because having the two functions is easier in my opinion. You could also combine them later on and simplify but it’s definitely easier to read through.

Comment: One should always try to separate concerns. You wind up with simpler code, smaller, more reusable functions that are easier to test. And assuming you give things meaningful names, you wind up with code that is a lot easier for somebody new who lacks the domain knowledge to understand..